# Create custom PAGE with register_post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, metabox

The following code in functions.php outputs a post when I publish, not a Page:

```
// custom post_type for agenda
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );    
function create_my_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'agenda', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Agenda', 'add new on admin bar' ),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => false,
        'query_var' => false,
        'delete_with_user' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions' ),
    ) );}
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### The full problem:

I need to add a metabox to a page, but only the "agenda" page, I don't want this metabox to appear in every page in admin panel, so I'm creating a custom post_type with the exact same functions of a page, only with a different post_type to be able to set a metabox to it alone.

#### Screenshot of current output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPEx8.png
(can't post direct images yet, so please click link)

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot seems to indicate that you're interested in the status message for your custom post type saying `'Page updated. View page'`.  If that's true, the reason that you're getting `'Post updated. View post'` is that you haven't provided status messages for your custom post type.

Here's the code for the admin edit page (`edit-form-advanced.php`):

```
if ( isset($_GET['message']) ) {
    $_GET['message'] = absint( $_GET['message'] );
    if ( isset($messages[$post_type][$_GET['message']]) )
        $message = $messages[$post_type][$_GET['message']];
    elseif ( !isset($messages[$post_type]) && isset($messages['post'][$_GET['message']]) )
        $message = $messages['post'][$_GET['message']];
}
```

So the edit screen is trying to retrieve messages for your `$post_type` (agenda), not finding them, and displaying the post messages.

You can fix this by creating `$messages['agenda']` with something like the approach described on the [Register Post Type function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example):

```
function agenda_update_messages( $messages ) {
  global $post, $post_ID;
  $messages['agenda'] = array(
    // ...
    1 => sprintf( __('Page updated. <a href="%s">View page</a>', 'your_text_domain'),
                  esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    // ...
  ); 
  return $messages;
}
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'agenda_update_messages' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need to create a custom post type just add the metabox if the page is the one you require ex:

```
add_action('admin_init','meta_on_agenda_only');

function meta_on_agenda_only(){
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;

    // checks for post/page ID change the 00 to the ID pf your agenda page
    if ($post_id == '00' || is_page('agenda'))  {
        //add your metabox
        add_meta_box('meta_box_id', 'Meta Box name', 'callback_function', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
    }
    //hook the save action
    add_action('save_post','my_meta_save');

}
```

Comment: Bainternet, thanks for your time, but unfortunately that won't work for me. I have a startup company that make websites for end-users to edit, based on wordpress, so it will be a dynamic ID for each website... I'm brazilian, and the ppl who's going to use these websites have a really limited tech knowledge, so I thought of doing that way to keep it simplier as possible ... I'm pretty broken right now, but I'm hoping this project will help me bounce back!

Comment: Neverthless, this is a question that can be used in thousands of projects, not only mine... I've googled a lot and found a lot of questions, but no concrete answer about this :)

Comment: the ID is dynamic but the slug can be the same? its just makes no sense to create a post type just for a single page. if you want another solution, you can use custom field to determine if the metabox should be added or not

Comment: I've searched about custom_field and found an very interesting plugin: Advanced Custom Fields; However, that still didn't seem to solve my problem. The only problem I'm having right now that I really need help is that the code above outputs a POST, instead of a PAGE, and it must output a PAGE for reasons... Thanks for your time so far, any ideas?